# Storing Sub-Questions in a database for a Survey/Questionnaire System

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently in the process of creating my tables for a survey/questionnaire system. As I got to creating the questions table, I think I came across a slight issue that could impact the whole application if I continue. Within my questions table, I have a column called **"subBelongsToQuestion"**, which is an integer value for identifying which sub-questions belong to which parent questions (if any). Then in my answers table, I have a column called **"responseRevealSubQuestion"**, which is an integer value for identifying which sub-questions to reveal if the trigger answer within the **"responseRevealSubQuestion"** column value matches with the **"response"** column value.

So for example, if a user answered yes to a question such as "Do you like cheese?", then a sub-question would appear saying "What do you like about cheese?".

I am wanting to convert this vision into a database format and I wasn't sure if I should continue with the approach I am using, or to change? It is so that if say a user deletes a question that contains sub-questions, then the application can run the required code to also delete the sub-questions and trigger answers as well.

Comment: Using your desigen ,deletes can automaticly be handel by having FK's constrints ,you dont mention your database soultion ,many database soultions provide  the ability for on delete cascade ,in such case when you delete question all the relared childs data will be delete automaticly

Comment: elirevach - What you are saying is I should convert the mentioned columns into FKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for survey apps you dont use SubQuestions, you define flow conditions

Imagine you have this questions on your db

```
Q_ID   Question
 1     Do you like cheese?
 2     What do you like about cheese?
 3     Do you like meat?"
 4     What do you like about meat?
 5     ...
```

Then you have a flow table to validate after one answer.

```
Q_FROM   Q_VALUE Q_TO
  1        NO      3
  3        NO      5
```

In this case you only take detour for `NO` answer. otherwise you continue with the next question.

After your end each question you do

```
SELECT Q_to 
FROM FlowTable 
WHERE Q_from = @CurrentQuestion 
  AND Q_value = @CurrentAnswer
```

Comment: So you recommend I should add another database table to my system? But then how would I relate the two tables together. Would I do that through the use of FKs?

Comment: Yes, After your end each question you do `SELECT Q_to FROM FlowTable WHERE Q_from = @CurrentQuestion and Q_value =@CurrentAnswer`

Comment: OK I will try applying that logic to my ERD diagram later and will get back to you on that to see if it's turned out what I expected it to. So if the user says no, the query looks to see if that answer contains any sub-questions. If the user says yes, would the query still look to see if that answer contains any sub-questions? I'd imagine it would, but just need a second opinion.

Comment: I have done several app like this. But this is the basic case. You also may consider cases with multiple choices, then you need a more complex flow table

Comment: I had a look into this and I think for what I am wanting to try and achieve, can I still get the same results by stating what number position the question is at in the questions table, and what answer is required for the sub-questions to appear in the answers table? I already have a pivot table  for these two tables and it would be the case of querying which sub-question belongs to what question. If I had a sub-question in position 3.1, the system would know that it belongs to the question in position 3. Sorry if I seem to be diverting. I'm just trying to find a simple but effective solution.

Comment: Sound OK. I usually have Page attribute to tell what question will show together and think is similiar to your subquestion aproach

Comment: Ah OK. Good stuff. Thank you for the help and advice.